# How to reconnect to MySQL through SSH tunnel after connection drops?

Tags: mysql, ssh-tunnel

I use to connect to MySQL server (Debian Linux) through a SSH tunnel.
Yesterday I issued a complex query, that usually takes 30 min or so to complete.
After few minutes:

```
plink.exe: FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
Disconnected
```

The tunnel dropped the connection.
I was able to reconnect through tunnel to MySQL, but I was presented with a 'blank', new connection, with no indication about the status of my query.

Is there a way to prevent this, like "screen" does with ssh?
Any suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to establish standard ssh-session with `putty`, log in, launch `screen` and then start mysql CLI-client:

```
/usr/local/etc > mysql -u imdba -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 108316807
Server version: 5.5.41-MariaDB FreeBSD Ports

Copyright (c) 2000, 2014, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> USE test;
Database changed
MariaDB [test]> call long_running_stored_procedure();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to establish a standard ssh session.

Comment: You haven't the shell on the remote host? May be the easiest way to passby that restrictions - is to create an `event` that will be launched by `mysql` at desired time, and all the results have to be stored in some tables for further preparation.